# React Native: Getting this error in Android when running the app: error: package com.beefe.permission does not exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-permissions

I am trying to implement QR Scanning for which I had to install RNCamera & react-native-permissions. After doing all that, app run successfully in iOS Simulator but in case of Android, getting the error:

> error: package com.beefe.permission does not exist

I find this mentioned in **build.gradle** file in dependencies:

```
implementation project(':react-native-permissions')
```

what am I doing wrong?